# How to add autocompletion entries to Xcode

Tags: xcode, codesense

I noticed that there are some words that XCode does not recognize. For example the word initWithCoder.  It also won't recognize NSString if the word const comes before it. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You mean "Code Sense." First, try opening your project info panel and clicking "Rebuild Code Sense Index." Failing that, file a bug at [bugreporter.apple.com](http://bugreporter.apple.com).